# Hosting native window views in Flutter app with Platform Views?

Tags: windows, flutter, win32gui, flutter-plugin

I am working on plugin which require native view. I done the changes for android and ios with help of [platform integration](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/ios/platform-views). Now I am trying with window support and I could't find any official support. Is there any third party library or any progress on window support?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open issue for this [#31713](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31713). You can upvote this issue.